# Xamarin Android game fail to load ads (even test ads) with Ad failed to load : 3

Tags: android, xamarin.android, admob

My Rewarded and Banner ads from AdMob used to work perfectly. I haven't changed any code. I feel like they stopped working since I pushed my app into Closed Testing. Now no ads ever show anymore, even the Test Ads. I also tried adding my devices as test devices in AdMob, but no luck.

Here's how I create the Banner Ads:

```
var adView = new AdView(ContextHelper.Current)
{
    AdSize = AdSize.SmartBanner,
    AdUnitId = Constants.Ads.AdMobBannerUnitId,
    LayoutParameters = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WrapContent, LayoutParams.WrapContent)
};

adView.LoadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().Build());
```

Here's how I create the Rewarded Ads:

```
private static void CreateRewardedAd()
{
    RewardedVideoAd?.Dispose();
    RewardedVideoAd = new RewardedAd(ContextHelper.Current, Constants.Ads.AdMobRewardedUnitId);
    RewardedVideoAd.LoadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().Build(), new InternalRewardedAdLoadCallback());
}

private class InternalRewardedAdLoadCallback : RewardedAdLoadCallback
{
    public override void OnRewardedAdLoaded()
        => base.OnRewardedAdLoaded();

    public override void OnRewardedAdFailedToLoad(int p0)
        => base.OnRewardedAdFailedToLoad(p0);
}
```

And I use Google's Test ID's:

```
internal const string AdMobBannerUnitId = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111"; // Test Ad Id
internal const string AdMobRewardedUnitId = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/5224354917";  // Test Ad Id
```

Anyone have ANY clue as to what is going on? I have no errors in the AdMob account.

Comment: error code 3 is no fill.. https://support.google.com/admob/thread/3494603?hl=en

Comment: @Amod Gokhale   No Fill for Test Ads?  Something doesn't seem right.

Comment: you are right, it should work with test ids... can you try to add test device and try ( add device id as test id )?

Comment: I have them added in Admob account, do you mean adding them through code instead ?

Comment: yes, add them through code

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work.

Comment: can you upload your error log as well? It should work with test ids..

Comment: I am having the same problem. error code 3 on test ads and real ads. Test ads worked a month ago and I haven't changed anything. Same code, same project, same device, that worked before. I have not upgraded software on the computer or device either.

Comment: Same here, I had no code changes and things just stopped working.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a google bug. Other developers are having the same problem. I also tried the crazygames ads SDK and the test ads are now failing when they didn't fail a week ago. https://support.google.com/admob/thread/69754742/test-ads-not-showing-with-error-ad-failed-to-load-3?hl=en

Comment: I'm sure it it, both my test ads and production ads don't show, very frustrating.

Comment: You can still get ads to show when testing if you register your device as a test device. Google is probably not motivated to fix this bug because they want to you register your devices with them. Similar to how adMob payment setup by bank deposit has been broken for months because they prefer you so set it up by giving them your bank login.

Comment: Doesn't work in my case, even with registered devices.